# One DVI cable isn't working with new graphics card?

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, vga, dvi

I've just bought a new 750 Ti, and unlike my old 5750 which had 2x DVI-I ports, this has 1x DVI-I and 1x DVI-D, but I'm not sure if that's causing the problem here:

[image]

I've also noticed that my two DVI cables are different... one converts to VGA which works fine, and the other is a regular DVI lead which doesn't:

[image]

Does anyone please know what could be causing this problem? I've tried switching around the cables into both ports, and either way the monitor with the DVI lead doesn't work - but the DVI to VGA monitor works regardless of which of the ports it's connected to.

Similarly when I plug the DVI to VGA cable into the other monitor, it works fine, so I'm thinking the problem isn't with the monitor either.

**Update: oddly, the two monitors are now working just fine, however, the one still doesn't work in the BIOS/during boot (not ideal since it's the main monitor, the other is very much secondary) and also right before loading into Windows, both monitors turn off for around 10 seconds... not quite sure if there's any way to fix it though.**

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The difference between DVI-I and DVI-D is that the DVI-D only outputs a digital signal. Your monitor may be analog so it is not compatible. It may also be that you've disabled the auto-select source option on your monitor and it is stuck on analog now. Look for a way to select the digital source on your monitor. If this isn't available then I'd guess that you have an analog only monitor. Most LCDs do support digital input though so this is unlikely.

http://nvidia.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/221/~/what-is-the-difference-between-dvi-i-and-dvi-d%3F